# open selected wordpress post with javascript

Tags: posts

I'd like to create a link that opens the selected post via javascript onclick in the loop.

If I use `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>More...</a>` in the loop it opens the correct post.

But If I use

```
<script>
function open_win()
{
window.open("<?php the_permalink(); ?>")
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="open_win()">More...</a>
```

it just won't open the correct selected post. How can I make this work?

Comment: have you read the codex page for [`the_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink)?

Comment: Javascript is client side (only in the browser), PHP is server side (can't be used in the browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
<script>
function open_win( thePostURL )
{
window.open(thePostURL);
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="open_win( '<?php the_permalink(); ?>' )">More...</a>
```

It seems like a bit more work than it's worth though, the following would have the same result of the [link opening in a new window](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp):

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">More...</a>
```

Comment: I need to get the URL with the right post ID dynamically though. That's the problem. And I can't do it with a normal HTML link.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding, so what sort of issue are you having with the top code snippet then?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the code before. The top code snippet works like a charm. Thanks